# Retrieve Local Tomcat Path for File Access

Tags: tomcat, gwt, file-access

Is there a way to retrieve the Tomcat local GWT directory in order to save a file?

In order to retrieve a file it's

```
new File(getClass().getResource(nameOfAFile).getPath());
```

Therefore how would I retrieve path of the tomcat host in order to save a file 'hello.xml'?

Comment: I am also trying to get my gwt app path on server to access files on server. I tied to use ServletContext.getRealPath() in the server side java class (the service implementation), but it is not resolvable. I get the error:
"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getContextPath() from the type"
Can I know how you used this or any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tomcat, you can use [ServletContext.getRealPath()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) to get the path for a file in your webapp then you can do navigate to "../" to find tomcat dir.